# IOS 8 Adaptive Layout. Different Layout for ipad orientation

Tags: ios, ios8, size-classes, adaptive-design

Can some one please give me some idea of how to use universal storyboard to show different layouts for iPad portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment. I have filed a bug report as wanting a new feature to be added to make it possible. I'll keep you updated.